# VBA looping through all series within all charts

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I'm having an issue with the looping through of several charts in my VBA code. I'm 99.7% sure that this is a really easy and quick fix but my brain isn't working today.

I want the code to loop through every chart on the ActiveSheet, and for every data series that the chart contains I want it to add the last value of the series. In my example I have 9 charts, each with 3 series in them (bound to change, some have 2 but I digress).

I have the following code

```
Sub AddLastValue()
Dim myChartObject As ChartObject
Dim myChart As Chart
Dim mySrs As Series
Dim myPts As Points

With ActiveSheet
For Each myChartObject In .ChartObjects
    For Each myChart In .Chart
        For Each mySrs In .SeriesCollection
            Set myPts = .Points
            myPts(myPts.Count).ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlShowValue
        Next
    Next
Next
End With

End Sub
```

If I remove the looping code and just do a

```
Set myPts = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart. _
    SeriesCollection(1).Points
myPts(myPts.Count).ApplyDataLabels type:=xlShowValue
```

Then it works for that specific chart and series, so I'm positive it is the looping that I'm messing up.

Could someone tell me where I mess up the looping code?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try following code:

```
Sub AddLastValue()
    Dim myChartObject As ChartObject
    Dim mySrs As Series
    Dim myPts As Points

    With ActiveSheet
        For Each myChartObject In .ChartObjects
            For Each mySrs In myChartObject.Chart.SeriesCollection
                Set myPts = mySrs.Points
                myPts(myPts.Count).ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlShowValue
            Next
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: And it works like a charm :) I tried a similar solution to this without the Chart variable, but I think I see now that it was the second For, the mySrs In .SeriesCollection that messed it up because adding the myChartObject.Chart.SeriesCollection did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome) basically, the problem was because of lines like `For Each mySrs In .SeriesCollection`. In `With` statement it means `ActiveSheet.SeriesCollection`, (but not `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Chart.SeriesCollection`)

Comment: Aaah, that makes sense. I'm still not through all the Lynda courses yet so I have a lot to learn ^^

Answer (score 1):

Not work for empty values.

This code find last not empty value and then adds label.

```
For Each mySrs In myChartObject.Chart.SeriesCollection
      Set myPts = mySrs.Points
      Dim i As Integer
      i = myPts.Count
      Do Until i < 2 Or mySrs.Values(i) <> ""
        i = i - 1
      Loop
      myPts(i).ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlShowValue
Next
```