# How to define colors by series in Excel scatter plot with connecting lines

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a scatterplot with data for many countries over a period of 20 years. I already have the graph made, with the points for each country linked with a connecting line to show how each country's outcomes against both variables have evolved over the time period.

However, rather than having a different color for each country (the Excel default), I would like to group the countries to show trends across them -- e.g., all lower-income countries blue, all middle-income orange, and all upper-income green. However, they have to stay as separate series (I can't just stack the data into one column per color), so that the connecting lines stay separate for each country.

How can I loop through all countries in the plot to change the colors according to a defined variable outside of the plot?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165581/vba-looping-through-all-series-within-all-charts, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46575647/vba-code-to-change-fill-color-of-series-on-chart

Comment: Thanks very much Tim -- was able to use those to make this work. Appreciate the direction!